# Is there any way to post a webhook using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, discord, webhooks

I want to send a message in my Discord server using a Webhook. Is there any way to do that using JavaScript?

I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
var url = // Webhook URL
var text = '{"content":"Hi"}' // Text to post
$.ajax({
   data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
    "text": text
   }),
   dataType: 'json',
   processData: false,
   type: 'POST',
   url: url
});
```

[Souce](https://gist.github.com/achavez/9767499).

Comment: @Boy With Silver Wings Thanks a lot! Hope it works :)

Comment: if you want to post a json you should specify ` contentType: "application/json"` in your request. Also `'payload={"text": "..."}'` is not a valid json payload.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Discord Webhook Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    function sendMessage() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/676118118082281513/ZS5YcWhurzokBrKX9NgexqtxrJA5Pu2Bo4i7_JsIxC-JIbPBVhSZkcVVukGOro52rnQA");

      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

      var params = {
        username: "My Webhook Name",
        avatar_url: "",
        content: "The message to send"
      }

      request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

A WebHook url is still a Universal Resource Locator [is it not](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook)? [They are typically defined on Http](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook#Function) so if you want to call a Webhook you would do so over Http. This means a typical [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) request can make a WebHook call.
In your case, you are posting a `“Hi”` message to the WebHook so it should look something like this:

```js
var url = // Webhook URL
var text = {content: "Hi"}

fetch(url, 
  {
    method: “POST”,
    headers: {“Content-Type”: “application/json”},
    body: JSON.stringify(text),
  }
)
  .then(res => •••); /*Do whatever you want with the response when it arrives.*/
```

The assumption is that the WebHook expects a payload with `Content-Type”: “application/json”` via a `Post` request at that endpoint.
**AFAIK**, WebHooks are a way servers communicate with each other not client-server communication but that’s disputable.